# Why I cannot pass photos to ASP.NET MVC controller when using flow.js

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am using ASP.NET MVC and angularJS and try to upload photos to a DB with flow.js. However, I cannot find photos in my MVC controller. Did I miss anything? Thanks.
Here are my codes:

1. view

```
<div ng-app="photo.upload" 
     ng-controller="psPhotoUploadController"
     style="max-height:930px; overflow-y:auto;padding-left:80px; padding-right:80px;">
    <div flow-prevent-drop flow-drag-enter="dropClass='drag-over'" flow-drag-leave="dropClass=''">
        <div flow-init 
             flow-file-added="!!{png:1,gif:1,jpg:1,jpeg:1}[$file.getExtension()]">
            <div class="drop" flow-drop ng-class="dropClass">
                <span class="btn btn-default" flow-btn>Upload Image</span>
                <span class="btn btn-default" flow-btn flow-directory ng-show="$flow.supportDirectory">Upload Folder of Images</span>
                <b>OR</b>
                Drag And Drop your images here
                <span type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="color:blue; position:absolute; right:130px" ng-show="$flow.files.length" ng-click="uploadToDatabase($flow)">Upload</span>

            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <div ng-repeat="file in $flow.files" class="gallery-box">
                    <span class="title">{{file.name}}</span>
                    <div class="thumbnail" ng-show="$flow.files.length">
                        <img flow-img="file" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped" ng-class="{active: file.isUploading()}">
                        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"
                             aria-valuenow="{{file.progress() * 100}}"
                             aria-valuemin="0"
                             aria-valuemax="100"
                             ng-style="{width: (file.progress() * 100) + '%'}">
                            <span class="sr-only">{{file.progress()}}% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" ng-click="file.cancel()">
                            Remove
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

2. typescript controller

```
namespace pspace.Controllers {
    var angularModule = angular
        .module("photo.upload");
    angularModule.config([
        "flowFactoryProvider", flowFactoryProvider => {
            flowFactoryProvider.defaults = {
                target: "",
                permanentErrors: [500, 501],
                maxChunkRetries: 1,
                chunkRetryInterval: 5000,
                simultaneousUploads: 1
            };
        }
    ]);

    export class PsPhotoUploadController {
        static IID = "psPhotoUploadController";
        static $inject = ["$scope", "$http"];

        constructor($scope, $http) {
            $scope.uploadToDatabase = function ($flow) {
                var formdata = new FormData();
                angular.forEach($flow.files,
                    function(value, key) {
                        formdata.append(key, value);
                    });
                var request = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/photos/UploadPhotos',
                    data: formdata,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                    }
                };
                $http(request)
                    .success(function(d) {
                        alert(d);
                    })
                    .error(function(e) {
                        alert(e);
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    angularModule.controller(PsPhotoUploadController.IID, PsPhotoUploadController);
}
```

3. MVC c# controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadPhotos()
{          
    var httpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request;
    if (httpRequest.Files.Count != 0)
    {
       ///////The problem the Count is always 0
       Upload to the DB
    }
    return null;    
}
```